# Modelling using GLM

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, biostatistics

I am doing species distribution modeling using GLM with 18 presence locations and 45 absence locations. Among 25 predictors (19 bioclimatic, soil moisture, distance to forest, distance to road, solar radiation, aspect, elevation), I selected eight predictors after collinearity test and fit them in a model but none of them were significant.

```
    Call:
glm(formula = RV ~ aspect + bio10 + bio12 + bio4 + forestdist + 
    roaddist + soilmoisture + solarrad, family = binomial, data = crisfinnPA)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.1281  -0.9472  -0.6255   1.3032   1.9496  

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  -45.201251 154.754168  -0.292    0.770
aspect         0.004206   0.004212   0.999    0.318
bio10         -0.395404   1.069799  -0.370    0.712
bio12         -0.010945   0.008885  -1.232    0.218
bio4          -0.034707   0.041306  -0.840    0.401
forestdist    -4.495176  86.868312  -0.052    0.959
roaddist       0.005171  17.123314   0.000    1.000
soilmoisture  -3.595371  12.132649  -0.296    0.767
solarrad       0.009568   0.017017   0.562    0.574

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 73.304  on 59  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 68.793  on 51  degrees of freedom
AIC: 86.793
Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

I then tried to fit an interaction term and saw the summary, all of them were significant.This seems weird to me.

```
Call:
glm(formula = RV ~ aspect + bio10 + bio12 + bio4 + forestdist + 
    roaddist + soilmoisture + solarrad, family = binomial, data = crisfinnPA, 
    weights = bio10 * bio12)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-951.6     0.0     0.0     0.0   976.1  

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error    z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   1.422e+17  4.263e+07  3.336e+09   <2e-16 ***
aspect        4.495e+12  1.015e+03  4.426e+09   <2e-16 ***
bio10        -2.121e+14  2.915e+05 -7.275e+08   <2e-16 ***
bio12        -6.319e+12  2.394e+03 -2.640e+09   <2e-16 ***
bio4         -1.729e+13  1.020e+04 -1.696e+09   <2e-16 ***
forestdist   -3.578e+16  2.479e+07 -1.444e+09   <2e-16 ***
roaddist      1.298e+16  4.611e+06  2.815e+09   <2e-16 ***
soilmoisture -1.519e+16  3.133e+06 -4.850e+09   <2e-16 ***
solarrad     -1.181e+13  4.707e+03 -2.510e+09   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance:   863403  on 59  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 18999357  on 51  degrees of freedom
AIC: 18999421

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25
```

Can someone please explain what may be the problem?

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem ? A model with interaction is completely different than a model without so it is entirely plausible for associations to become significant after including an interaction. I would be more concerned about the extremely small  and large estimates.

Comment: That is the thing I am concerned about too and thats why I thought it has some problem. As we compare both the results, the estimates and AIC value of the model with the interaction terms are very different, also the deviance residuals.

Comment: As mentioned, they are different models, it is no surprise that the estimates, standard errors and fit statistics are completely different.

Comment: Why are you using the value of a predictor as the weights?

Comment: You have a small dataset and run the risk of absurd results if you fit over-complicated models. Detail: `aspect` is never a variable to be offered directly as a predictor; you usually need to handle it as sine and cosine terms.

Comment: You are not fitting an interaction term! As @DemetriPananos notes, you are using *weights* calculated as the product of two predictors!

Comment: What is `RV`? The science here may guide some simpler models.

Comment: I don't see any interactions in the second model, just weights. Is it a valid way of defining interactions? I've never seen it before and I've never thought about it, but it might be.

Comment: I am actually new to all these. May be I am wrong but I tried fitting the interaction like this: m1=glm(RV~aspect+bio10+bio12+bio4+forestdist+roaddist+soilmoisture+solarrad,bio10*bio12,family=binomial,data=crisfinnPA)  and the result is posted from this model. Isn't this the correct way to fit interaction?

Comment: RV here is response variable with presence (1) and absence (0).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not significance of any terms: it is the fact that you pass `weights = bio10 * bio12` to the model.

The problem is even more evident when you look at the estimates and standard errors which are on the order of $10^{10}$ and $10^7$ in some cases respectively.

Regardless, we should expect estimates to change when new terms are added, especially interactions.  If your concern is a lack of significance, I've got news for you; adding terms to your model to get the stars to appear is *p-hacking*.

Please edit your question with more details about your problem.  We can then advise you on the best approach which is honest and defensible give the data and your hypothesis.

Comment: I have edited my question with details about my data.